# How can I get a variable from another class in Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the **id_categories** variable in class MainActivity types for use in methods LoadListFoodbyId (**int id**) in class ListFood.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_store_View);
        LoadCategories();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoriesClickListener());
}
    // The click listener for ListView in Store List
    private class CategoriesClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            Categories item = cateAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent itent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListFood.class);
            itent.putExtra("item", item);
            int id_categories = item.getId(); //i want to get this variable
            String log = "ID: " + id_categories;
            startActivity(itent);
            Log.d("ID: ", log);

        }
    }
```

ListFood.java

```
public class ListFood extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_dish);
        LoadListFoodbyId(4); //use variable in here
}
    public void LoadListFoodbyId(int i) {
        DataApdapter mDbHelper = new DataApdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        ArrayList<Food> listFoodById = mDbHelper.getAllFoodById(i);
        listFoodAdapter = new ListFoodArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_dish,
                listFoodById);
        lv.setAdapter(listFoodAdapter);

        mDbHelper.close();

    }
```

I tried calling the method LoadListFoodbyId (int i) in the class mainActivity by ListFood:

```
ListFood lf = new ListFood(); 

lf.LoadListFoodbyId (id_categories)
```

and try the other way is to take variables in class MainActivity id_categories used in class ListFood by MainActivity:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity(); 
LoadListFoodbyId (main.getId ()),
```

but all were unsuccessful.

Comment: `MainActivity main = new ();` and `LoadListFoodbyId (main.getId ())`, are you sure you are writing Java?

Comment: Send it with `intent Extras`

Comment: never instantiate an Activity by hand, use the Extras bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You add it to the intent.

   ```
   Categories item = cateAdapter.getItem(position);
   Intent itent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListFood.class);
   itent.putExtra("item", item);
   int id_categories = item.getId(); //i want to get this variable
   String log = "ID: " + id_categories;
   itent.putExtra("id_categories", id_categories) //you can call your variable whatever you want, I have called it "id_categories" for convenience.
   startActivity(itent);
   Log.d("ID: ", log);
   ```

   2. Open it in the ListFood class, whenever you need it.

   `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    int id_categories = bundle.getInt("id_categories");`

Answer (score 2):

In your MainActivity class define the variable id_categories example:

```
public class MainActivity {

 private int id_categories;
  ...
```

change this line code

```
 int id_categories = item.getId();
```

in

```
 id_categories = item.getId();
```

and create a function in class MainActivity

```
public int getIdcategories(){
    return id_categories;
}
```

Comment: Yes only an error of cut and paste i correct it thank's

Comment: How can i use getIdcategories() in class ListFood? I've tried MainActivity main = new MainActivity(); 
LoadListFoodbyId (main.getId ()) the result is always zero.

Comment: ListFood lf = new ListFood(); 
lf.LoadListFoodbyId (<MainActivity>.getIdcategories());

Answer (score 2):

put it in an intent in your main activity, like this

```
itent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
```

and retrieve it in list food like this

```
int id=getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0); // 0 is default value if id is not found in intent
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `id_categories` as `public static int id_categories` in `MainActivity` before onCreate. Then you can access it in any class as `MainActivity.id_categories`.